# static page sizing or dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is not really a answer I NEED but it is more of a curiosity for me. I personally make my webpages dynamically by checking screen size then create my divs from that size. Now what would be the benefits of a 'static' sizing(like using px) over my method?

Comment: How about you make your CSS use ems and percentages and media queries instead of relying on JavaScript? Liquid Layouts.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be the benefits to control over your design.  Plus, by generating your pages' content entirely on the fly, you're making the (usually, but not always safe) assumption that your uses have javascript enabled.  Without a fallback default, what are those non-JS users going to see?

Personally, I'd opt for making large-scale adjustments based on screen/window sizes that fall within a range.  That way you're not having to dive into the DOM every time a user adjusts their viewport, plus, as I said earlier, you've got a great deal more control over how your content is presented.

Just my two cents...

Comment: Well the way i do it is i just grab the width and make the height based on that so it always stays in ratio, on the other hand i currently do not have the knowledge to make a fallback default as you called it i suppose that would include a php page that redirects after checking if javascript is enabled?

Comment: A fallback default would just be the styles applied to the page in lui of any javascript modifications (your style.css file).  It's a base principle of progressive enhancement.  First make sure that your raw content is independent and, at the very least, accesible (imagine you're using a screen reader to surf the web), then style using CSS (which is how your page'll display without any javascript), THEN you can start playing around with scripts.  The key rule is to ensure your content is not script generated.

If you approach it this way, your site will always be viewable, if not pretty.

Comment: ohh I see now, so all I have to do is use css to style my page and use my javascript after the fact?

Comment: Pretty much.  But getting back to your initial question; it'd be better to create styles tailored to the different screen sizes.  the easiest way to do this would be to add a class to your body tag and then prefix you CSS declarations with that class, eg:

      `.content            //Your default layout`
      `.small .content     //Your small screen layout`
      `.mobile .content    //Your mobile layout`

that way all you have to so is use javascript to determine what range your users' viewports fall into and append the body tag with the appropriate class.

Comment: another useful aspect of my method is when on a mobile device i can simply swap the height and width when detected so it stays the same ratio

Comment: I can't really imagine a scenario where viewing something on a mobile device would by optimized simply by changing the aspect ratios of the original content, unless your content is purely text, and even then...

Sounds like you need to dig a little deeper into CSS before you'll be able to to get any value out of asking this question.

Comment: I understand css plenty I have css styling on my page, but when i tested the usual page it loaded with a more vertical design than my current horizontal one, so by checking if it is mobile it swapps the two to compensate for phones usually being upright instead of horizontal

Answer (score 0):

I determine which stylesheets I send to the browser based on the size of the window and type of device - but they are fixed width pages. I personally find it very difficult to write good looking websites that scale well and look good on both low and high resolution screens. Keeping control of 2 or 3 different "sizes" is much easier for me.

Comment: A very interesting idea, I am actually having a bit of an issue when going between browsers but as monners said not all users have javascript enabled so im not sure what i would do about that

Comment: You can still determine the user-agent without using javascript, and would be able to display either your "standard" fixed width stylesheet (960px), or your mobile stylesheet. No javascript. However, for gigantic resolutions, can provide a stylesheet that accommodates that screen size if javascript is enabled.

Comment: very cool what language would you use to determine the 'user-agent'?

Comment: You can use a lot of different languages (including javascript) but I use PHP - if (preg_match('/iPhone/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) echo "iPhone user!"; You can also use .htaccess files without having to do any programming to display a completely different website depending on the user too (for mobile sites for example): RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPhone.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://MOBILE.MyWebsite.com [R=301]

Comment: I have not learned any php yet does it have as much functionality as javascript? and is it enabled mroe often than javascript

Comment: It gets executed on the server, not in the web browser. So, it is impossible for the user to "disable" PHP. The PHP code gets called before the server actually starts handing out any HTML or javascript to the web browser.

Comment: The functionality is different, it is to be used in combination with javascript. Javascript can interact with the user after the webpage has already loaded. PHP is meant to work behind the scenes before the webpage has loaded. Using your original question as an example, I could determine the user-agent with PHP and then decide whether or not to display the mobile site or not. Then, if it is not a mobile site, send them to our normal site which has some javascript on it to determine the window size and do different things from there. Lots of options!

Comment: Okay I see I am currently using javascript to detect if the user is on a mobile device which i can now see would not be very effective for all users. I suppose it is time to dive into php

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for javascript execution also delays the time that users can start reading your content, and is not always desirable.

And sometimes an art designer would actually do that layout designs, where you just put in the vital codes to make things work... And they happen to use a lot of static image sizes for decoration...

Accessing dom can be slow and expensive, for some pages that I just want to see the content fast and clear, maybe all those resizing really isn't necessary.

Comment: understandable the reason I am currently using javascript in the way I have described is more of a personal preference for my current project(mainly because I like that it does not scroll no matter what resolution it is) so if I wanted this same result how could I do so without javascript

Comment: I am not sure if this works on all browsers yet... But for simpler page design.. you can set width and height of divs to a percentage of the window size in css style definition. Then the browser would take care of the resizing. For complicated layout designs... I am not sure.. sometimes individual browsers treats css rules differently.

Comment: that is what i tried initially but when you have different resolutions it can mess up the ratios of a page

Comment: well... you can selectively choose the kind of components to set a percentage based size, and some components to use static size. With percentage based location, those static sized items will just float along the scaling... But to ensure everything looks ok in all kinds of resolutions and aspect ratios... i think it's not possible without extensive testing.
I think javascript aided styling is more desirable when your layout becomes complicated. And complicated layout and decorations usually means lots of stuff to load anyway... doesn't matter that much to wait for javascript anymore